.NET The network path was not found error on win server 2016
Using c#, I run my code in one computer perfectly fine, and in another machine I got this error:
System.IO.FileNotFoundException: The network path was not found.

   at System.DirectoryServices.AccountManagement.UnsafeNativeMethods.IADs.Get(String bstrName)
   at System.DirectoryServices.AccountManagement.CredentialValidator.BindSam(String target, String userName, String password)
   at System.DirectoryServices.AccountManagement.CredentialValidator.Validate(String userName, String password, ContextOptions connectionMethod)
   at System.DirectoryServices.AccountManagement.PrincipalContext.ValidateCredentials(String userName, String password, ContextOptions options)
   at CheckMemberStep(String& username, String password)

Code:
using (var context = new PrincipalContext(currentContextType))
  {
    step.IsReady = context.ValidateCredentials(user, password, ContextOptions.Negotiate);
  }

I gave logon user necessary permissions such as log on as a service and access from a network. And still getting this machine specific error. May you give me any insights?
Machine is Win server 2016 64 bit
.Net version 4.6.2
It is a WPF application. Context is set as ContextType.Machine. Logon user is the user running the app.

What's the actual context you used to run this code? Console application or web app on IIS? The term "log on user" is ambiguous, so you have to edit the question to reveal more detais.

It is a WPF application. Context is set as ContextType.Machine. Logon user is the user running the app.

You probably have authentication error.  Running a net application before net 4.7.1 the encryption libraries have issue.  Starting in 4.7.1 many of the encryption errors were fixed.

@jdweng thank you. And, do you have any explanation for the fact that it works in one machine and not in another one? .net app was designed using 4.6.2 but would it make any difference if the running machine has a higher version of .net? It could be the reason why it works smooth in my computer as it has .net 8 loaded on?

What is the target version of Net?  It is not the version of Net installed but the target that is important.

Target version is 4.6.2 and i really could not figure out why it works fine in most of the computers and does not work in this specific machine

Do the other computers that run the program without problems also have Windows Server or is it just this computer? Running specific Windows programs with C# sometimes in Windows Server may be associated with problems. Install a "WMware Workstation" on your computer and install a Windows 10 in it and test if your application gives errors inside this virtual machine. If it doesn't give an error, you should check the Microsoft docs to see what are the restrictions on "PrincipalContext" for Windows Server.

@BabakM, I also tested in another Win server 2016 machine. It works fine in other Win Server 2016 also in 2019 as well. It is definetelly a machine specific error which I could not manage to find out. I doubt if it is firewall related as I can run many commands related to AD using command prompt. There does not seem to be any other problem

There is a small possibility that the bug is in that particular .NET class. Upgrade the .NET target and see if it resolves. For example, .NET 4.8 or rewriting it in .NET Core 6 using other way.

@BabakM. The reason I am using .Net 4.6.2 is to be able to run it in more machines. All about customer needs. But I  guess there is no other way in such cases.

Yes, maybe so. In any case, this .NET 4.6 may be removed from Microsoft's support in the not too distant future. It is you who makes the trade-off between possibilities and limitations, and probably your thinking is more correct.

Also check windows security log while this exception happens as more information would be logged there at the time this method is failing. It related to some SAM authentication issue, maybe password of the local account is not consistent across machines

@user246821 It is different. I dont get error while creating the context but during the validation.

This question is similar to: C# PrincipalContext The network path was not found. If you believe it’s different, please edit the question, make it clear how it’s different and/or how the answers on that question are not helpful for your problem.

After searching in the dark corners of the internet for your weird issue I've found that remote directory access was removed from Windows 7 and onwards if the user is not part of the local workgroup, check here. I am not 100% sure if this is your specific issue, but I am 60%. So maybe the issue is caused by the fact that the user is part of the local workgroup on those machines and it is working, whereas the user is not part of the local workgroup on this particular machine.

If you found another StackOverflow post that you believe solves the issue, why didn't you vote to close the post as a duplicate?

Hi, but in my case user is a local user. I can see the user in local workgroup and even an administrator. So, I think my problem is different

@NeilT:  I use the phrase vote to close in a broad sense. While I forget the exact  option to click on (perhaps Flag?) one can mark a post to be sent to one of the review queues where someone with the appropriate permissions will review it. Since you have less than 3000 points perhaps you can find the appropriate option(s). Something simple one can do, is to mention that a post appears to be a duplicate in a comment.

@user246821 is that mandatory?

is that mandatory? No, integrity is a choice. It's something one chooses regardless of whether or not someone else is watching. Of course, as with anytime there are choices, some people make a poor choice.
